# How to convert a large ERP system (about 52 modules) from VB.NET webforms (.aspx) to ASP.NET Core MVC using C# (.cshtml)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-core-mvc

We have real world (used in many companies) ERP system with about 52 modules, it's a VB.NET webforms app running on .NET 4.8.

Now we want to convert it to ASP.NET Core MVC and C#, and want to structure it with clean architecture (domain, application,  infrastructure, ASP.NET Core Web API).

It's not practical to rewrite the entire system. I think it's not hard to convert the business logic code (classes) from VB to C#, I think the complexity is with how to convert the webforms (`.aspx`) pages to views in ASP.NET Core MVC (`.cshtml`).

Is there any strategy or solution help to do that, and is it better to use a front-end framework (e.g Angular)?

Comment: Such questions are explicitly off-topic for SO.

Comment: Why it is off-topic? I couldn't find any resources or guidelines?just If you know anything you can help

Comment: Asking for tools is one of the explicit reasons for closing a question, as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I meant any method or approach, not exactly soft tool.

Comment: It's important to actually say what you mean, but that is still too broad a question anyway.

Comment: Can you help and edit the question to be good question, please

Comment: I'm afraid it's not for me to decide what question you're asking. If the question you want answered is off-topic then it's off-topic. There would be other sites and forums that are OK with such questions so you can use them and come back here if and when you have a more specific question that is on-topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253618/discussion-between-alnajm-and-jmcilhinney).

Comment: This really is solely a business decision you're expecting us to make for you.  There are many tools that help with various aspects of code conversions, all with their own pros, cons and limitations that you need to evaluate for your context.  That said, you're really talking about moving to a whole new technology stack for your UI, to me that's a re-write of the UI (Not talking just a vb ->c# conversion).  Underlying business logic though (assuming currently separate namespace) can be left as vb.net for the time being as that can be referenced very easily from a C# project.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I want to know about any way to reuse webforms controls, I don't want to rewrite all UI

Answer (score 1):

You reasoning about the Pages is correct, I think the best way to do it is to write a new UI. If your development team would like a short learning curve, you can do it in MVC core, if you team would like to learn something new, can be Angular or any other Javascript Frontend will do.

for the clases conversion I recommend this:
https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter/

It's the better tool and extensions you can use for VB.net to C# conversion